# How to improve PanResponder efficiency in ReactNative?

Tags: react-native, events

I am using React Native for a game (perhaps not the best framework but not the point). I need user to be able to slide on a grid. On the pic, user is selecting *MKEC* without removing its finger from screen.

I am from the web, so I thought I would use onHover event. But it dossn't exist on mobile. So I created a parent component and a grid component. Parent component catch event with PanResponder, and I calculate where user finger is on the grid, and change state of the grid component.

However, if user is going too fast from on letter to another, it sometimes 'skip' a letter. If you go from M to G (first column) very fast, it seems that not event is triggered on H. Am I clear ? User feels latency.

```
componentWillMount() {

    const onRelease = (evt, gestureState) => {
        this.props.validateWord();
    };
    const onMove = (evt, gestureState: GestureState) => {
        const obj = Object.assign({}, {
            pageX: evt.nativeEvent.pageX,
            pageY: evt.nativeEvent.pageY
        });

        const pos = {
            x: evt.nativeEvent.pageX - this.position.pageX,
            y: evt.nativeEvent.pageY - this.position.pageY
        }
        const whatSquare = whatSquareIsTouched(
            pos,
            defaultLetter.width, // size of letter
            defaultLetter.width * 0.22 // padding for diagonale
        );
        const letter = this.props.gridReducer[whatSquare.y]
        && this.props.gridReducer[whatSquare.y][whatSquare.x] ?
            this.props.gridReducer[whatSquare.y][whatSquare.x] : null;
        // if letter => if touch is on a letter and not outside of grid comp
        if (letter) {
            this.props.letterTouched(letter, whatSquare.insidePadding);
        }

    }
    this._panResponder = createResponder(onMove, onRelease);
}
```

How could I improve my code ? Or perhaps go another way to tackle this problem?

[image]

**Update after comment :**

I have not solved the problem yet. But i tried the following. I assumed that when user change direction, a new event is trigger. So I could calculate the finger path. If user starts at M and finish in G without changing direction, then H has been hovered.

Comment: Hi, did you handle this problem? cause I'm facing such thing now.

Comment: I've updated my post.

Comment: So how do you check user direction? How do you prevent him/her crossing another direction to get to G from M